# Navigation close onClick of another list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how I can expand on the function at the moment, so that when one navigation is open, when the user clicks to open the other navigation, the navigation which is open presently collapses?

Please find the code below;

http://jsfiddle.net/N7xgC/

Comment: You can use a selector directly to attach an event handler to multiple elements, you don't need to use the `.each()` function and then attach them individually.

Comment: Any chance you can edit my fiddle please with the correct code, newbie to jquery

Comment: Forgot to mention this earlier, but you should really include the relevant code in the question in addition to providing a jsFiddle so that it continues to be useful even if the fiddle is not accessible.

Comment: Will do for the future ... cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're currently doing is toggling the display of all elements with the `sub` class, so clicking on any link will display all of the sub menus. Instead, you want to hide all of the elements with the class `sub` that aren't a sibling of the link being clicked on, and then toggle only the element with the class `sub` that **is** a sibling of the link being clicked on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main > li > a').click(function() {
        var sibling = $(this).siblings('.sub'); // select the <ul> to exclude
        $('.sub').not(sibling).hide(); // hide everything except that element
        sibling.toggle(); // toggle that element
    });
});
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/N7xgC/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated your jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N7xgC/6/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.main > li > a').click(function(event)
  {
      $('.main > li > ul').hide();
      $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

Comment: That loses the toggle functionality when clicking on the same link twice in a row.

Comment: That wasn't specified in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/N7xgC/10/

**EDIT:** A bit of a cleanup, with single click handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/N7xgC/11/